# Set CSS value by a given JSON

Tags: css, json

Given a flat structured JSON e.g

```
{
  "borderColor": "red"
}
```

The value can be passed to CSS like this

```
div {
  border: solid 10px {{borderColor}}
}
```

I would love to replicate this behavior and use JSON files to configure my CSS.

I first encountered this while making a widget for StreamElements and cannot figure out, how this was done.

Google and read the code base.

Comment: As in [`element.style.borderColor = '#000'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)?

Comment: I do not quiet get it. How is js involved in this? And yes, the js snippet would produce the same result.

Comment: CSS can't process external data like JSON by itself. It's just not part of the language spec. The widget authoring process you've experienced must have some kind of behind-the-scenes process built in to translate and insert JSON values into CSS properties. To replicate it in the front-end, your best bet would be to use JavaScript to parse your JSON data and manipulate any relevant CSS statements that correspond to it. We'd need a more concrete context to help provide practical feedback.

Comment: Look more closely at wherever you found this example. It must be using some sort of preprocessor to convert that pseudo CSS into real CSS.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript you could set CSS variables via `el.style.setProperty(--cssKey, value)` after you have the JSON key/values, but we'd need a more concrete context to help provide practical feedback.

Comment: @Bumhan Yu comment is the answer to the question. Ty